# How to extract content from a csv file and pass as variable in body of Jmeter Script

Tags: jmeter

In a transaction we are uploading a file and the contents are also passing the transaction as shown below.We have to upload multiple files and some files have 100 rows also. How to pass the content of the file in below format.

------WebKitFormBoundaryCiwylbob4VrtpsP3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fuSpreadsheet"; filename="File.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

Assessment,Component ID,Centre,Candidate No
H472,02,10107,9049
H472,02,10108,9002
H472,02,10108,9011
H472,02,10108,9100
H472,02,10108,9128
H472,02,10108,9129

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfHVb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be creating the [multipart POST request](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.html) yourself, leave it to JMeter.

In the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

1. Tick `Use multipart/form-data` box
2. Switch to "Files Upload" tab and provide full or relative path to your file, the [file input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_file.asp) name and the [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) of the file you're uploading.

[image]

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

If you're uncertain regarding how to properly build a file upload request - you can just [record it using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure to copy the file(s) you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation prior to executing the request in the browser.